# DIBS recurring payment, no error message, not working at all

Tags: php, payment-gateway, credit-card, recurring-billing, dibs

I am using the following code to work, but it is not working

```
  require('DIBSFunctions.php');

     //Define input variables (here simply static variables)
  $Merchant     = "123456";
  $OrderID      = "AHJ798123AH-BH";
  $Currency     = "208"; //DKK
  $Amount       = "30000"; //In smallest possible unit 30000 Øre = DKK 300 
  $CardNo       = "5019100000000000"; //DIBS test Dankort values
  $ExpMon       = "06"; //DIBS test Dankort value
  $ExpYear      = "13"; //DIBS test Dankort value
  $CVC          = "684"; //DIBS test Dankort value
  $MD5['K1']    = "~.(S96%u|(UV,~ifxTt.DAKSNb&SKAHD"; //K1 and K2 MUST be gathered through
  $MD5['K2']    = "qJuH6vjXHLSDB*%¤&/hbnkjlBHGhjJKJ"; //ones DIBS admin-webinterface.

//Call function DIBSAuth to authorise payment
  $RES = DIBSAuth($Merchant,$Amount,$Currency,$CardNo,$ExpMon,$ExpYear,$CVC,$OrderID,$MD5);

  echo '<pre>';
  print_r($RES);


//Check the response (the DIBS API returns the variable transact on success)
  if ( $RES['transact'] != "" ) 
  {
    printf ("Authorisation successful! TransaktionID = %s",$RES['transact']);   

//Call function DIBSCapt to capture payment
    $RES2 = DIBSCapt($Merchant, $Amount, $RES['transact'], $OrderID);

    if ( $RES2['status'] == "ACCEPTED" ) 
    {
      printf ("Transaction completed");
    } else {
      printf ("Capture failed!");  
    }
  } else {
    printf ("Authorisation failed");
  }
```

This is the code output
            Array
         (
             [reason] => 2
             [status] => DECLINED
         )
          Authorisation failed

```
    require('DIBSFunctions.php');
```

this file contains the username and password, I am providing it. e.g.

```
    function http_post($host, $path, $data, $auth="") {
        $auth['username']       = '123456';
        $auth['password']       = '987656656';
       //rest of the code
    }
```

if someone wants to see the file 'DIBSFunctions.php' it can be downloadable from here http://tech.dibspayment.com/toolbox/downloads/dibs_php_functions/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i contact to the technical support and got the answer below:

The problem you are experiencing is due to the fact that you are trying to send us real card numbers (test or live). This form of integration requires a PCI certification of your systems.

Most customers use a so called hosted solution, where you use our payment windows. Please refer to tech.dibs.dk for documentation.